# Can't use progresql in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I'm importing a exists grails project, this project use postgresql use remote postgresql, they built it on real machine, now I need do it on my localhost machine, and use postgresql local.

Everything is OK, but the system can use postgresql, althought I set up it in datasource.config. My datasource.config is similar to old real one, just change something between remote server and local server. Here is my datasource.config.

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'

}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    production {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    username = "postgres"
    password = "postgres"
    dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate'
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/faql_dev"
    }
}
```

Here is some error I got:

```
Caused by: org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.HibernateGpsDeviceException: {hibernate}: Failed to index the database; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query using scroll
at org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.indexer.ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer.performIndex(ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer.java:172)
at org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor$1$1.doInCompassWithoutResult(ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor.java:104)
at org.compass.core.CompassCallbackWithoutResult.doInCompass(CompassCallbackWithoutResult.java:29)
at org.compass.core.CompassTemplate.execute(CompassTemplate.java:133)
at org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps.executeForIndex(SingleCompassGps.java:147)
at org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor$1.call(ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor.java:102)
... 5 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query using scroll
    at org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.indexer.ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer.performIndex(ScrollableHibernateIndexEntitiesIndexer.java:118)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "QUESTION" not found; SQL statement:
```

I imported everything involve to postgresql, So I can create table based on domain in development mode, but I can't run it. In production, it will throw that exception.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the FULL DataSource.groovy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException
```

This suggests to me that you're using the wrong JDBC driver. The data source configuration you've posted only sets the app up to use Postgres in *production* mode, if you run locally in dev mode then it'll use the default H2 database.

Comment: As I said, it will create table in development mode, so, I don't know why at development mode, it stops at `Configuring Spring Security OAuth ...` and wait for input(althought it's still not continue) and show time out error later. Here is all `| Loading Grails 2.1.0
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 6 source files.....
| Running Grails application

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

Configuring Spring Security OAuth ...`