# Table not found; SQL statement

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.4 and hibernate 2 with GGTS (Groovy/Grails Tool Suite). I've created a DB and some tables and already granted their permissions to the user. I'm receiving the 'Table "XX" not found; SQL statement...' message.

```
Table "TESTING_TABLE" not found; SQL statement: select this_.cod_test as cod_test1_0_0_, this_.version as version2_0_0_
from testing_tab this_ [42102-176]
```

I have 2 dataSources and the class only uses one of them ( the dataSource_testing)

This is how my DataSource file looks like:

```
dataSources {
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"

    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
dataSource_testing {
    jmxExport = true
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
    driverClassName: 'org.postgresql.Driver'
    pooled = true
    properties {
        validationQuery="select 1"
        testWhileIdle=true
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=60000
     }
}
}
hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache = true
//cache.use_query_cache = false
cache.use_query_cache=true

//    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
development {
     dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        logSql = true
    }
    dataSource_testing {
         username: 'usrx'
         password: 'usrx'
         //url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_xxx'
         url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_xxx'
         dbCreate: 'update'
    }
  }
test {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = 'update'
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_xxx"
    }
  }
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        properties {
           // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
           jmxEnabled = true
           initialSize = 5
           maxActive = 50
           minIdle = 5
           maxIdle = 25
           maxWait = 10000
           maxAge = 10 * 60000
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
           validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
           validationQueryTimeout = 3
           validationInterval = 15000
           testOnBorrow = true
           testWhileIdle = true
           testOnReturn = false
           jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
           defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
        }
    }
    dataSource_testing {
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
        driverClassName: 'org.postgresql.Driver'
        username: 'usrx'
        password: 'usrx'
        url: 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_xxx'
        dbCreate: 'update'
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my BuildConfig:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
// configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
//  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

// configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
// configure settings for the run-app JVM
run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
// configure settings for the run-war JVM
war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
// configure settings for the Console UI JVM
console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
// inherit Grails' default dependencies
inherits("global") {
    // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
    // excludes 'ehcache'
}
log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"

    //repo for spring security
    mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
}

dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
    runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1201-jdbc41'
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
}

plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55.3" // or ":tomcat:8.0.22"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    // asset-pipeline 2.0+ requires Java 7, use version 1.9.x with Java 6
    compile ":asset-pipeline:2.2.3"
    compile ":quartz:1.0.2"
    compile ":joda-time:1.5"


    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.10" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

    // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
    //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
    //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
    //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
    //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
  }
}
```

And here is the mapping of my class:

```
class TestClass {


static mapping = { 
    datasource 'testing'
    table 'testing_table'
    id name: 'codeP'
    codeP column: 'cod_test'
}
long codeP
```

Already tried this:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=943887 ,checked my JDBC driver following this solution: [Can't use progresql in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075479/cant-use-progresql-in-grails), and this: [H2 in-memory database. Table not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763747/h2-in-memory-database-table-not-found), [Table "XXXXX" not found; SQL statement:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054985/table-xxxxx-not-found-sql-statement), [Grails throws Table "xxx" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907303/grails-throws-table-xxx-not-found), searched on the GORM Reference Documentation
without success

Comment: in the error message, is from testing_table this_ [42102-176]. Sorry =)

Forgot to ask for help. 
Anyone knows how to proceed?

Comment: I've found that error to be frustratingly misleading. I'd double-check those permissions. That's what got me. You can connect to PostgreSQL with psql with the same credentials and run the same query in the error message.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Thanks for your comment. Yeah, the permissions are fine. Tried a SELECT * FROM and works. It seems to me that something is wrong with the connection between the application and the DB. I tried to use the 'postgres' user in the application but still get the same error.

Comment: Ok. So this points to Grails. Your domain class has the datasource set to *testing*, but the datasource name in the config is *dataSource_testing*. Have you tried making these two names match?

Comment: I tried it now and no more "TABLE NOT FOUND". Thank you! I'm just a little frustrated because here: (http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources) they use _dataSource_something_ in the config and _something_ set as the datasource.

Comment: Oh, that's not good. I checked Grails 2.4.4 and it also has the same mistake. The Grails 3 documentation has it right. Just to clarify, are you using Grails 2.2.1?

Comment: No, I'm using the 2.5.1.
Now I'm receiving a "Method on class [] was used outside of a Grails application" =(

Comment: Yeah, that's a common error. Generally speaking, it usually happens when trying to use a domain class outside of a Grails service, controller, or view. If you want, just get with me on Google Hangouts. That error is typically easy to sort out. https://plus.google.com/u/0/109886199751744223967/posts/p/pub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of this question is incomplete, because I don't know why it is working now. It's in this post of mine.
[Multiple data sources configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549958/multiple-data-sources-configuration/33578673#33578673)